# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos x^n}{n}$ converge on $-1\le x \lt 1 $, and uniformly converge on $(-1,0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Given the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos x^n}{n}$$

This is similar to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

This series converges on $-1 \le x \lt 1$ and converges uniformly on $(-1,0)$

If I use the root test, for the above series, I get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{(n)^{\frac{1}{n}}} =\left(\frac{x}{1}\right)=x$$

And then if $|x|\lt 1$ it converges, greater than $1$ diverges and $x=1$ we get a known series that doesn't converge. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you for correction. I think i've corrected my mistake now.

Comment: Why do you believe that this series converges?  What test(s) have you applied to support that thesis?  For $x\ge 0$, this series clearly diverges by comparison with the harmonic series?  And since $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ it diverges for all $x\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Apologies. I seem to have found what was confusing me. Using the ratio test and on both of these series seemed to have fixed any issues I had.

Comment: The two series are not similar. Examine the behavior of the numerators of the terms in each case as $n \to \infty$. For any $x \in (-1,1)$, we see that $\cos(x^n) \to 1$ whereas $x^n \to 0$. This alone does not prove convergence or divergence, but it highlights an important difference.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, precisely.  I've just posted an answer that reflects your comment.  -Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is ***not*** "similar" to the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$.

Note that for $|x|<1$, $-1<x^n<1$, with $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n=0$.

Therefore, we have for $|x|<1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos(x^n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1+O\left(x^{2n}\right)}{n}\right)$$

which diverges by comparison to the harmonic series.